# get_object_or_404 with values

Tags: python, django

**views.py:**

```
def car(request, car_id):
    car = get_object_or_404(Car, pk=car_id, active=1)
    return render(request, 'car.html', {'car': car,}
    )
```

in **car.html**:

```
...
{{ car.mark }}, {{ car.options.year }}, etc.
...
```

So, I have **many** requests to my db. In another view I use

```
all_cars = Cars.objects.all().filter(active=1).values(...)
```

And in this variant I have only 2 request to db.

Yes, I know, that I can use in car`s view:

```
car = Car.objects.filter(id=car_id, active=1).values(...)[0]
```

Is any other variants to do the same with get_object_or_404 or something, that not doing many requests to db?

Thanks!

Comment: If you just want one item you shouldn't you use `Car.objects.get`

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to filter by car_id and active feilds in single query ?

Comment: @TanveerAlam I want to use model`s fields in template with minimum number of request to db. If I use get_object_or_404 I have many requests

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass a queryset as the first parameter, instead of a model class. Here you can use `select_related` (and `prefetch_related`, but it seems you need the first one) to reduce database queries:

```
def car(request, car_id):
    cars = Car.objects.select_related('options')
    car = get_object_or_404(cars, pk=car_id, active=1)
    return render(request, 'car.html', {'car': car})
```